# Leaflet layer switcher on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to open the Layer switcher control in leaflet 1.0 on click instead of hover.
The example is here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

I tried extending the L.Control.Layer and adding a click event, similar to the focus event in the leaflet source (below).

I even tried changing the 'focus' to 'click' event in the initLayout function from the leaflet-src.js and it does not work.

The relevant code from leaflet-src is here:

```
if (L.Browser.touch) {
    L.DomEvent
        .on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
        .on(link, 'click', this.expand, this);
    } else {
        L.DomEvent.on(link, 'focus<changed to 'click' here>', this.expand, this);
    }
```

I also tried jQuery to change the event on the link after it's loaded but still didn't have luck.